# How long can a concrete pool stay empty when ground water is not a problem?

Tags: concrete, pool

I live in Las Vegas, you know- the desert.  Ground water is not a problem here, when it does rain, it either evaporates incredibly fast or is absorbed very deep very quickly.  I also live on a small rise so any natural water runs downhill away from my property.

I have a concrete pool, it was re surfaced (about 1 1/2-2 inches) 3 years ago.  I have drained my pool before and left it empty for about 2 weeks with no problems.  I want to drain it now and fill it in the spring.  It is green and gross, but I'm going to be gone for about 2 months and don't have the time to care for it before I go ( or the money to pay someone to care for it). If I just leave it while I'm gone it'll be bug ridden and cause that kind of problems.  So if I drain it now and put a cover over it to protect it from direct sunlight will I still have a pool come spring?  Or just a hole full of concrete crumbles?

Comment: Is this a salt water or chlorine/baquacil treated pool? It should not be green. I'd suspect if you "cover" it so its not being beaten on by the sun it would be ok, but I'm not a pool expert nor concrete expert of pools. Do you have a plug to allow ground water in? (just in case)

Comment: Why do you think the concrete will deteriorate if you leave it dry and/or exposed to the sun?  Concrete is the most common exterior construction material.  It is normally dry and exposed to the sun.  All concrete gets hairline cracks when it cures.  Breaking up is usually cause by ground settlement and loss of support.

Comment: Noybman, No plug for water to enter (believe me, ground water is NOT a concern).  I know it SHOULDN'T  be green.  I had been working 12-20 hour shifts for a while, and didn't keep up the chemicals.   Leaves and crap got in...now it's green.

fixer1234, I just hear/see all these people saying how bad it is to leave the pool dry.  "It'll crack" "you'll ruin it" whatever.   I figured it'd be ok.  I just needed a second opinion.   Thanks

Comment: Why would you protect concrete from sunlight ?